# Save div Html and Css in database via ajax post.

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, database

I am try to make save option for editable dives And also i am using Ckeditor for editing.I am searching on google many times but i did find any simple and authentic example.Actully i need when user done editing via Ckeditor than div content css and html save in Database.Is that possible.

For example i have some example content.look at below.

**Html**

```
<div id="editor" contentEditable='true'; ><i>Company</i><br><b>Bigbang</b>
<div><img src="simple.png"></div>
</div>

<button>Save</button>
```

**Css**

```
#editor i {width:200px;border:1px solid #fff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/%E2%80%8E)

```
<div id="editor" contentEditable='true'; ><i>Company</i><br><b>Bigbang</b>
<div><img src="simple.png"></div>
</div>

<button id="btnSave">Save</button>

$.ajax({
     url: yourUrl,
     type:"POST",
     data: $("#editor").html();
     success:function(data){alert(data);}
});
```

Comment: I have been tried already this method but return nothing.My php code is if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
$save=$_POST['data'];
echo $save;}